# Devise User Profile empty fields are shown inside the custom view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to show a devise user provide inside another view.

Homeprivate/profile.html.erb:

```
<%= render "devise/registrations/edit" %>
```

I just converted the default edit view into a partial. To support the user to be available as a "resource", I have the following helper.

```
module HomeprivateHelper
 def resource_name
  :user
 end

 def resource
   @resource ||= User.new
 end

 def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
 end
end
```

But if I sign in, and go to /homeprivate/profile -- I see all fields are empty. Somehow the current user is not mapped to the form. How do I map the current user to the profile view if it is displayed in a custom view? Seems like User.new is used, not the current user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to rails, but I got the same issue and figured out how to fill those empty fields. In your helper, instead of `user.new` use `current_user`. It should look like this:

```
def resource
@resource ||= current_user
end
```

That should work.